# MySQL How to get First Sunday and last Saturday of previous month using curdate()

Tags: mysql

I really need help with the correct way to get the first sunday of the previous month and the last Saturday of the previous date using curdate().

This is what I am using for the current month:

```
 select date_add(curdate(),interval -DAY(curdate())+2 DAY) 

 select adddate(last_day(curdate()),-mod(weekday(adddate(last_day(curdate()),6)),2))
```

But I am looking for guidance on the correct SQL for the previous month. My goal is the get the last rolling 12 months data broken out by month over month but cannot get the between the first sunday and last saturday correct. Please help!!!

Comment: You ask *first sunday of the previous month*, but label it in the SQL as *...of this month*. What is *last Saturday of the previous date*? In the SQL you name it *of the current month*... Can you please update your question to make it consistent?

Comment: Hi trincot, sorry if that was not consistent and i appreciate the response.  I removed the label of both sql's.  Those are what i am using to get the current months data but need help on the correct way to get the previous months data.